# Sending a file from java client to PHP web-server (yahoo web hosting)

Tags: java, php, file-upload, webserver, client

I need to upload a file from java client running on my system to web-server(yahoo hosting) using PHP script. I have java code and php code as follows. The java program is not showing up any error and running successfully but the text file is not being uploaded to web server. Please help and suggest necessary changes.

**javaClient.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class javaClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.xyzAbc.com/project_files/upload.php").openConnection();
        httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        File myFile = new File ("/Users/pp/Documents/client_file.pdf");
        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        OutputStream os = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis= new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

        System.out.println("Sending the file of size:"+ mybytearray.length + " bytes");

        os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

        System.out.println("File sent.");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpUrlConnection.getInputStream()));

        String s = null;
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        os.flush();
        bis.close();
        os.close();
        fis.close();
        in.close();
     }
}
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php 

$target_path = "uploads/"; 

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded"; 
} 
else{ 
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!"; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
echo $_POST["name"];
echo $_POST["address"];                                                  
$img = $_FILES['img'];
  if ($img){
    $dir = dirname('File directory');
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($img['tmp_name'] as $value){
        $filename = $img['name'][$i];
        if ($value){
            $savepath="$filename";
            $state = move_uploaded_file($value, $savepath);
            if($state){
                echo $filename." Successfully Uploaded.";
            }
        }
        $i++;
```

Comment: Change the dirname to yours.

Comment: I tried replacing the php code but still did not work! 
Please let me know if any other changes should be made.